# Vagrant localhost production

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, macos-sierra

I have questions about virtual machine using vagrant. I need to install vagrant on a mac, but not for development mode. Just in production. My website runs localy on my mac and every day I need to run vagrant to use my website. It's important to know I won't to make my website online. How can I do that automatically ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Anyone one can answer this question ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the vagrant up, to access your Vagrant Box, it is because your box has been turned off. Unless you are physically turning off your machine, this should not happen.

If you are using a mac you could automate the vagrant box to startup boot of your system using the automator, something like this.

https://www.lifewire.com/automate-opening-applications-and-folders-on-mac-2260908

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I have another question.. Is that a good idea if I want to install a cms localy using vagrant for one of my client ? Isn't usefull than a desktop application ? I'm using a point of sales localy and a cms for online order ?